# how to use string variable in HTML.toHTML()?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have one EditText in my application, which is used for storing its content as HTML to a SQLite DB.

When I put an apostrophe in the text (e.g. Ajinkya's application), the EditText data is not getting inserted into the database because it treats the first apostrophe as a query break.

I tried many different suggested solutions here, but without success. For example I replaced "'" with "\'" but still the code (see next code block) is not replacing that symbol after converting to html.

```java
String NotesContent = Html.toHtml(notes_content.getText());
String Notestitle = Html.toHtml(notes_title.getText());

if (Notestitle.contains("'")) {
    Notestitle = Notestitle.replace("'", "\'");
}

if (NotesContent.contains("'")) {
    NotesContent = NotesContent.replace("'", "\'");
}
```

So I tried replacing "'" with "\'" first when I save the EditText data to a string variable to then convert it into HTML (see next code block). But the function HTML.toHTML() is not accepting string variables.

```java
String NotesContent = notes_content.getText().toString();
String Notestitle = notes_title.getText().toString();

if (Notestitle.contains("'")) {
    Notestitle = Notestitle.replace("'", "\'");
}

if (NotesContent.contains("'")) {
    NotesContent = NotesContent.replace("'", "\'");
}

Notestitle = Html.toHtml(Notestitle); // does not accept Strings!
```

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Replace `'` with `''` (two times apostrophe) before inserting the string/s in the in the db.

Comment: Hi Fantomas, ```''``` worked for me. below is my query i replaced ' with '' ```DELETE FROM temp_notes_db WHERE notes_title = 'king Aj' and notes_data = 'ajinkya''s username is king AJ in clash royale' and notes_date_time = '13/01/2020 07:24'```. but my doubt is, i am inserting one time apostrophe in DB and when i want to delete the entry i am replacing single apostrophe with  ```''``` (two times apostrophe) in query and it works. can you please explain me how it works ? how the query understands to delete the entry with one apostrophe ?

Comment: `''` is the oldest trick to overcome the `'` string limiter since SQL-92 was created.

Comment: Nowadays there are more efficient ways to do that. I encourage you to study all of them and find out the most appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) conveniece method this will escape the string.

As an example (using *When I put an apostrophe in the text (e.g. Ajinkya's application), the EditText data is not getting inserted into the database because it treats the first apostrophe as a query break.* (note with some HTML added) as the data to store and retrieve) :-

The Database Helper **DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE = "htmlstore";
    public static final String IDCOLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String HTMLCOLUMN = "html";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_htmlstore_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + "(" +
                IDCOLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                HTMLCOLUMN + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_htmlstore_table);
    }


    public long insert(String html) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(HTMLCOLUMN,html);
        return db.insert(TABLE,null,cv); //<<<< does the escaping for you
    }

    public String getHTML(long id) {
        String rv = "";
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE,new String[]{HTMLCOLUMN},IDCOLUMN+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(HTMLCOLUMN));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

The invoking activity **MainActivity.java** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView NotesTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NotesTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.notesview);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        // Inserts into the database
        databaseHelper.insert(
                "When I put an apostrophe in the text <b>(e.g. Ajinkya's application)</b>, " + //<<<< BOLD ADDED
                        "the EditText data is not getting inserted into the database " +
                        "<i><strong>because it treats the first apostrophe as a query break</strong></>." //<<<< Italic String ADDED
        ); 
        // Extracts from the database and sets the notesview TextView with the extracted text from the HTML (if any)
        NotesTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(databaseHelper.getHTML(1L)));
    }
}
```

The result :-

[image]